# Do not export unit tests in same package as main code to Java module

Tags: java, java-module

I have `main` and `test` packages in Maven project:

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       ├── module-info.java
│       └── <com.example>
└── test
    └── java
        └── <com.example>
```

I added `module-info.java` file to migrate project to Java module system:

```java
module com.example {
    exports com.example;
}
```

Unit tests are located in the same package as main code to test package-private classes in `main`: `com.example`;

When I try to compile it with Maven, it warns because some test dependencies are not exported:

```
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] .../src/test/java/com/example/Test.java:[18,33] interface wtf.g4s8.oot.TestCase in module  is not exported
[WARNING] .../src/test/java/com/example/SomeTest.java:[22,43] interface wtf.g4s8.oot.TestCase in module  is not exported
[INFO] 2 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] .../src/test/java/com/example/Test.java: warnings found and -Werror specified
[INFO] 1 error
```

It seems Java is trying to export my test classes, but I don't really want it. Is it possible to exclude it from module?

Comment: Modules don’t export classes, they export *packages*. Your module exports the package `com.example` and that’s it. The warning message, however, is incomprehensible.  Are the two spaces in “in module  ” indicating an empty module name, i.e. the unnamed module? Your module declaration has no `requires` directive, so it can’t use any other module (except `java.base`). And if the interface in question is not exported, how can the class(es) use it at all? It seems, whatever is generating the warning is following its own rules, not Java’s module system’s.